# Getting an ARN for an imported Kinesis stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

I have two nested Cloudformation stacks - the first template needs to define a Kinesis stream, the second needs to use a reference to that stream's ARN, as an argument to a further nested stack.

So it seems I need to "export" the stream from the first template, and "import" it into the second (following AWS docs on importing/exporting values across stacks) -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html

My export code [truncated] looks like this -

```
Outputs:
  MyKinesisStreamOutput:
    Value:
      Ref: MyKinesisStream
    Export:
      Name: my-kinesis-stream      
Resources:
  MyKinesisStream:
    Properties:
      Name:
        Ref: AppName
      ShardCount: 1
    Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
```

Whilst my import code [truncated] looks like this -

```
MyNestedStack:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    TemplateURL: !Sub "https://s3.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/my-nested-stack.yaml"
    Parameters:
      AppName: my-nested-stack
      KinesisStream:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              my-kinesis-stream
          - Arn
```

But then I get the following Cloudformation error -

```
Template error: every Fn::GetAtt object requires two non-empty parameters, the resource name and the resource attribute
```

and suspect I am falling foul of this -

```
For the Fn::GetAtt logical resource name, you cannot use functions. You must specify a string that is a resource's logical ID.
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html

Assuming I am exporting and importing the Kinesis stream correctly, how then am I supposed to get its Arn value ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you export something in `Outputs`, it's just a string, you can no longer `GetAtt` on it in the importing template.

What you need to do is to additionally export ARN:

```
Outputs:
  MyKinesisStream:
    Value: !Ref MyKinesisStream
    Export:
      Name: my-kinesis-stream
  MyKinesisStreamArn:
    Value: !GetAtt MyKinesisStream.Arn
    Export:
      Name: my-kinesis-stream-arn
```

Comment: Great to know that you got it working! Could you please post both the Output setting from the first stack and the Import code from the second (nested) stack, as I am currently stuck with exactly the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: @user3792245 See my answer for the `Outputs` and OP question for the import code.

Comment: Thanks @lexicore. I can see the Outputs in the first stack, but when I try to import it in the second stack, I am getting the following error "Invalid template parameter property 'Fn::GetAtt'"

Comment: @user3792245 You might want to ask a separate question. And make sure to include your templates ([MCVE] versions of them).

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two potential ways:

<strike>1) `Fn::GetAtt:[!ImportValue my-kinesis-stream, Arn]`</strike>

Sorry wasn't reading carefully enough

or what I would prefer

2) Directly export the required value as output: `Value: !GetAtt MyKinesisStream.Arn`

Hope that helps!

Comment: "first" seems to be relative :)